# Understanding graph and functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

> The graph's origin point, where the axes intersect, represents zero. If $x$ is the side of a square, we assume it is neither zero nor negative, so the relevant curve would be only the right side of the parabola. Assume the square's side is $3$. Move vertically up from $3$ on the $x$-axis to the curve, then go left to the $y$-axis where you find that the square of $3$ is $9$.

Hello, this quote is taken from Calculus Made Easy and I'm learning calculus. 
I'm trying to understand what the above quote means.
In my understanding, my thoughts are:

$$y=(x+3)^2+3$$

If so, more thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: On the $x$ axis are the side lengths of a square and on the $y$ axis are the corresponding areas.  What's the relationship between the side length of a square and its area?  Is it $\text{Area} = (\text{side}+3)^2+3$? (I feel like the ancients might have had real troubles with geometry if the area of a square had such a complicated formula.  )

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly some context problem that's missing here (it involves a square). From my understanding of the text, the graph represents the area $y$ of a square as a function of the length of its side $x$. So the graph would be $y=x^2$, restricted to $x>0$. Part of the text tells you how to interpret a graph.